# Uploading large files won't work in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, upload

I have a web application (Java / spring / hibernate) running in production on Tomcat7.

I manage to upload files easily but now I need to be able to upload large files (I have a 36MB file to upload).

Whenever I upload a large file I get 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

The log show the following lines:

```
415157         2014-11-19 14:53:03,662 INFO [http-bio-443-exec-52] com.eloan.controller.api.UploadFileController WFPIRSUM.PRN uploaded! 
428860         2014-11-19 14:53:17,365 WARN [http-bio-443-exec-52] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound Request method 'POST' not supported
```

The first line is from my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/boi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@CheckSessionAnnotation(type = 99)
@ResponseBody
public Integer upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws E000EloanException {
    LenderDetails anss = usService.getCurrentUserLenderDetails();
    int totalLines = 0;

    if (null == anss) { // user not in session...
        throw new E666UserNotInSessionException("User not in Session");
    }

    // this is a fix for IE
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    // 1. build an iterator
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile mpf = null;

    String doc_type = request.getParameter("doc_type");
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    // 2. get each file
    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
        LOG.info(mpf.getOriginalFilename() + " uploaded! ");

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mpf.getInputStream(), "Windows-1255"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // LOG.info("read [" + line + "] doc_tyep [" + doc_type +
                // "]");
                lines.add(line);
                // boiService.addBankOfIsraelEntry(line, doc_type);
                totalLines++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("File upload error for ", e);
            throw new E107IllegalCallException("File Upload Error");
        }

    } ...
```

In order to support large files I've tried the following (set the max size in the multipart config as annotation and as function call:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 52428800)
public class EloanApiWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
/**
 * Supports FileUploads.
 */
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(52428800);
    return multipartResolver;
}
}
```

I've tried to set it in the server.xml connector:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" maxPostSize="52428800"
           keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/keystore" keystorePass="Lj6xK8sk"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" server="eLoanSecureBSD-Server" />
```

And in the web.xml file:

```
<multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>52428800</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

It won't work!

BTW - when I run in eclipse (using JETTY server from a main) it runs perfectly without any issues...

Thank guys!

Comment: Reading a large file in memory isn't very smart, in your case you have the file in memory and next start doing String concat (increasing memore and gc cycles). You don't want to hold a 40Mb file in memory twice.

Comment: Can you post the html form too?

Comment: Hi M. Deinum - I think you got it - I've raised the log level of spring and I think I'm running out of memory in the process and that is why it throw the error...

Comment: Could you please share the client code that is uploading the file?

Comment: Mithun - I'm using query upload file that can be found [here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was simply with the memory configuration of the Tomcat.
I was getting out of memory exception that I didnt C in the logs until I've set the org.springframework logs to debug (really can't understand why it was the situation).

After giving the process more memory it simply started to work well.

I'm adding here the log that I've seen if its interest any one...

`112361         2014-11-19 16:23:42,500 INFO [http-bio-443-exec-22] com.eloan.controller.api.UploadFileController wfpirsum.zip uploaded!     
120026         2014-11-19 16:23:50,165 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver Cleaning up multipart file [files[]] with original filename [wfpirsum.zip], stored at [/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/upload_54d020ea_b425_473f_a2c7_3dc7d8d4a330_00000001.tmp]    
120043         2014-11-19 16:23:50,182 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Could not complete request    
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [tomcat-servlet-api-3.0.jar:na]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]    
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]    
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space    
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:349) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at com.eloan.controller.api.UploadFileController.uploadBankOfIsrael(UploadFileController.java:91) ~[UploadFileController.class:na]    
    at com.eloan.controller.api.UploadFileController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$aa339559.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at com.eloan.aspect.CheckSessionAspect.checkSession(CheckSessionAspect.java:53) ~[CheckSessionAspect.class:na]    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631) ~[spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at com.eloan.controller.api.UploadFileController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9a9d7ba.uploadBankOfIsrael(<generated>) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]    
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    
120056         2014-11-19 16:23:50,195 DEBUG [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-ip-10-101-11-1001416406956159_ClusterManager] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource    
120056         2014-11-19 16:23:50,195 DEBUG [QuartzScheduler_quartzScheduler-ip-10-101-11-1001416406956159_ClusterManager] org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore ClusterManager: Check-in complete.    
120089         2014-11-19 16:23:50,228 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/404.html]    
120089         2014-11-19 16:23:50,228 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Looking up handler method for path /404.html    
120103         2014-11-19 16:23:50,242 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Did not find handler method for [/404.html]    
120104         2014-11-19 16:23:50,243 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping Matching patterns for request [/404.html] are [/*.html]    
120104         2014-11-19 16:23:50,243 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping URI Template variables for request [/404.html] are {}    
120104         2014-11-19 16:23:50,243 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping Mapping [/404.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@507f1f06] and 1 interceptor    
120105         2014-11-19 16:23:50,244 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@507f1f06]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported    
120106         2014-11-19 16:23:50,245 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@507f1f06]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported    
120106         2014-11-19 16:23:50,245 WARN [http-bio-443-exec-22] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound Request method 'POST' not supported`